# How to sort an alphanumeric array in ruby reverse

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting, alphanumeric

I want to sort an array to keep the years in ascending order and continue in the right sequence.

It is for a simple ruby ​​application.

Suppose my array is `a = [ "Influenza - 2015", "Influenza - 2019", "Influenza - 2016", "Hepatite B", "Influenza - 2018", "Influenza - 2017"]`

I want my output to be:

```
Hepatite B
Influenza - 2019
Influenza - 2018
Influenza - 2017
Influenza - 2016
Influenza - 2015
```

Comment: The shown output years are not _in ascending order_.

Comment: You need to edit to change “ascending” to “descending” to be consistent with the title and example.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort by regex match on numeric at end of string and fallback to string if there's no regex match, then reverse it.

```
a = [ "Influenza - 2015", "Influenza - 2019", "Influenza - 2016", "Hepatite B", "Influenza - 2018", "Influenza - 2017"]

puts a.sort_by{|s| s[/\d+$/] || s}.reverse
```

will output:

```
Hepatite B
Influenza - 2019
Influenza - 2018
Influenza - 2017
Influenza - 2016
Influenza - 2015
```

Comment: It doesn't work correctly because it's sorting by years. Try it for this array: [ "Influenza - 2015", "Influenza - 2019", "Influenza - 2016", "Hepatite B", "Influenza - 2018", "Influenza - 2017", "A - 2019", "A - 2016", "A - 2014"]

Answer (score 1):

Option using [String#split](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/String.html#method-i-split):

```
"Influenza - 2015".split(' - ') #=> ["Influenza", "2015"]
```

So,

```
a.sort_by{ |e| e.split(' - ').last }.reverse
#=> ["Herpes 1", "Hepatite B", "Influenza - 2019", "Influenza - 2018", "Influenza - 2017", "Influenza - 2016", "Influenza - 2015"]
```

Comment: Are you aware that herpes was first documented as a disease (by Athenaeus of Attalia) in 1 AD?

Comment: I didn't. But I didn't have any "Herpes 1" string in my array. It popped up from nowhere while sorting! Maybe for that! :))

Answer (score 0):

```
a.sort_by do |s|
  yr = s[/\d{4}\z/]
  yr.nil? ? [0], [1, -yr.to_i]
end
```

Sorting is done by pairwise comparisons of arrays using the method [Array#<=>](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E). See especially the third paragraph of the doc.